# Add/Edit Tags of XML File Using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml file which I would like to create a form/table around to add, edit and delete records using PHP.

Is there any way I can create a table that shows all results, and allows me to either edit or delete that particular row of the table which represents a full record within the XML file ?

i want to be able to add/edit/delete tags using my web browser only without editing the xml file on pc and uploading to FTP..

I need this done in PHP, javascript or any other way to do so.

> Please dont give me links for simpleXML coz i tried this and i didn't mange to make it work :(

it would be much appreciated if someone can help me!
Thanks!

my xml file (scores.xml) looks like that :

```
<Games>
<Game>
<Header> </Header>
<Row>B</Row>
<Date>07.10.2011 01:05</Date>
<Time>Finished</Time>
<HomeTeam>Team1</HomeTeam>
<Score>1 - 3</Score>
<AwayTeam>Team2</AwayTeam>
<InfoID>info2</InfoID>
<InfoData> </InfoData>
<Other> </Other>
</Game>
</Games>
```

Comment: *> coz i tried this and i didn't mange to make it work :(* — But that is the way it's usually done. Why not try to "make it work"? Or do you want some links to DOM XML instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quite simple example of using XML in php without SimpleXML, however SimpleXML would be a lot easier:

```
<?php
//Load the scores XML file
$scores = new DOMDocument();
$scores -> load('scores.xml');

//Get the <Games> tag
$games = $scores -> getElementsByTagName('Games');

//Create the new <Game> tag (Could probably be done better by first placing everything in an array or something)
$newGame = $scores -> createElement("Game");
$newGame -> appendChild($scores -> createElement("Time", "Finished"));
$newGame -> appendChild($scores -> createElement("Score", "2 - 5"));
$newGame -> appendChild($scores -> createElement("Row", "B"));

//Add the new <Game> tag under the <Games> tag
$games -> item(0) -> appendChild($newGame);

//Save again
$scores -> save('scores.xml');
?>
```

Comment: thx mate i appreciate your help!
can you tell me how i can connect a HTML Form with this php so when i click submit in the form get the info written on the XML ?

Comment: No problems, here's a simple example of how to create a form. You should probably add some type of security to it (For example a password field): http://pastebin.com/Zf8NyHAe

Comment: thanks mate thats awesome! its just perfect for adding new Game, but what if i want to edit existing one can i do that in some way ?

Comment: I threw something quick together that can edit games too, but it has one major weekness: It uses time as the identifier, so it can't be changed. If you need to be able to change it, you'll have to add an ID row to the xml file too. I'm sure it could be written better, but it works at least: http://pastebin.com/NMaVy6En

Comment: are you kidding me ? XD... THATS JUST PERFECT... ill work around with it!
THANK YOU SO MUCH !!!
I really appreciate the time you spent on to help me thanks a lot :)
too bad i can't rate up ur post coz im under 15 reputation! but ill later!
Thanks again!!!!!

Comment: i have one more question :) is there anyway i can delete a complete <Game> ? if yes can i know how please ?:)

Comment: You should check out the PHP manual for DOM: http://se2.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php There is a method called removeChild which can be used for this task, modified example of my last code: http://pastebin.com/nfmxapTu

Comment: and thank you again!...

i really appreciate your help!...
i still have one little problem...

if u have time to check it, i post it in a new question :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663814/add-html-codes-to-xml-file-using-php

Answer (score 1):

You may not have been using the SimpleXML library correctly. Take this simple example if you were to try to add content to Game->Other (currently empty)

```
$xml = <<<XML
<Games>
<Game>
<Header> </Header>
<Row>B</Row>
<Date>07.10.2011 01:05</Date>
<Time>Finished</Time>
<HomeTeam>Team1</HomeTeam>
<Score>1 - 3</Score>
<AwayTeam>Team2</AwayTeam>
<InfoID>info2</InfoID>
<InfoData> </InfoData>
<Other> </Other>
</Game>
</Games>
XML;

// first convert the existing XML into a SimpleXML Object
$xmlObj = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo "<pre>".print_r($xmlObj, true)."</pre>";

// update Other
$xmlObj->Game->Other = "lolz";
echo "<pre>".print_r($xmlObj, true)."</pre>";

// return as XML
$xml = $xmlObj->asXML();
echo "<pre>$xml</pre>\n";
```

The stuff in $xml is now the completely up to date XML. Now, if you had more than one game, you would need to iterate through the Game nodes by doing:

```
foreach($xmlObj->Game as $game) $game->Other = "Lolz";
```

This would update every single game's Other tag with the text Lolz. Obviously this isn't super useful but you would make sure to update only the node you want by assigning some sort of identifier or doing some logic. Anyway, for your basic example this should work and should be a start to getting your problem solved. Good luck :)

Comment: thx for help! can u tell me how i can get this done using a html form ?

Comment: For a form, @Ineentho gave a good idea about that. The way I dealt with editing a node in place was to iterate through the xml file (using simplexml in my case because the xml file was never huge) until I reached the node that had a certain id. Then I would update all the items in that node (by doing something similar to $game->Other="lolz"; ). I then regenerate the entire XML file using the asXML() function and that was enough for my purposes.

Comment: yes what Ineentho gave me worked perfect to add new row but not to edit existing ones.... anyway thanks A LOT for your help i really appreciate it! :)