# Add HTML Codes to XML file using PHP

Tags: php, xml

i have an xml file (scores.xml) which im using a php codes to add new Tags to it...

i have a tag called Header which contain some html code

```
<![CDATA[<tr><td colspan='7' id='headertd'>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img border='0' src='images/euro.png' />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
UEFA Euro 2012 Qualifications</td></tr>]]>
```

when im writing this code in the form of the pgp script and submiting everything goes normal to the XML file except the header tag.... im getting an error in the php script and the code is going in the xml tag like that:

```
&lt;![CDATA[&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td colspan='7' id='headertd'&gt;&#13;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#13;
&lt;img border='0' src='images/euro.png' /&gt;&#13;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#13;
UEFA Euro 2012 Qualifications&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;]]&gt;
```

so thats getting wong info to my xml...
is there anyway i can fix this ? and avoid the transformation of these codes?

thats my php code :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {//If the user submitted the form, then add to the XML file
    //Load the scores XML file
    $scores = new DOMDocument();
    $scores -> load('../scores.xml');

    //Get the <Games> tag
    $games = $scores -> getElementsByTagName('Games');

    //Create the new <Game> tag (Could probably be done better by first placing everything in an array or something)
    $newGame = $scores -> createElement("Game");
    $newGame -> appendChild($scores -> createElement("Header", $_POST['header']));
    $newGame -> appendChild($scores -> createElement("Row", $_POST['row']));
    $newGame -> appendChild($scores -> createElement("Date", $_POST['date']));
    $newGame -> appendChild($scores -> createElement("Time", $_POST['time']));
    $newGame -> appendChild($scores -> createElement("HomeTeam", $_POST['hometeam']));
    $newGame -> appendChild($scores -> createElement("Score", $_POST['score']));
    $newGame -> appendChild($scores -> createElement("AwayTeam", $_POST['awayteam']));
    $newGame -> appendChild($scores -> createElement("Other", $_POST['other']));
    $newGame -> appendChild($scores -> createElement("InfoID", $_POST['infoid']));
    $newGame -> appendChild($scores -> createElement("InfoData", $_POST['infodata']));

    //Add the new <Game> tag under the <Games> tag
    $games -> item(0) -> appendChild($newGame);

    //Save again
    $scores -> save('../scores.xml');

    echo "New game added.";
}
?>
```

and this php is connected to a form that looks like that :

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
<table id="table2">

<tr><td>Header:</td> <td><textarea style=" color:#000;" name="header" cols="73" rows="6" > </textarea></td></tr>

<tr><td>Row:</td> <td><input id='textfield' type="text" size="70" name="row" value='A or B' onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Date:</td> <td><input id='textfield' type="text" size="70" name="date" value='Date and time of the match' onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Time:</td> <td><input id='textfield' type="text" size="70" name="time" value='Current time' onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)"></td></tr>

<tr><td>HomeTeam:</td> <td><input id='textfield' type="text" size="70" name="hometeam" value='Home Team' onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Score:</td> <td><input id='textfield' type="text" size="70" name="score" value='Score' onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)"></td><td>"3 - 2"</td></tr>

<tr><td>AwayTeam:</td> <td><input id='textfield' type="text" size="70" name="awayteam" value='Away Team' onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Other:</td> <td><input id='textfield' type="text" size="70" name="other" value='Additional Info' onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)"></td></tr>

<tr><td>InfoID:</td> <td><input id='textfield' type="text" size="70" name="infoid" value='The ID of the Popup' onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" ></td><td></td></tr>

<tr><td>InfoData:</td> <td><textarea id='textfield' value='Data of the Popup' onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" name="infodata" cols="73" rows="6"></textarea></td><td>

<tr><td> </td><td><input type="submit" name="submitted" name="Add new row"></td><td> <td></td> 

</table>

 <style>
 BODY {font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#333; font-size:11px;}
 #textfield {color:#888;}
 #table2 td, tr { padding-right:10px;}
 </style>
```

Comment: Looks like you are using the htmlentities function or similar which is encoding html special characters like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error with PHP/XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660880/error-with-php-xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PHP function createCDATASection to add CDATA to your xml file:

Exchange

```
$newGame -> appendChild($scores -> createElement("Header", $_POST['header']));
```

for

```
$h = $scores -> createElement("Header"); //Create a empty <Header> tag
$h -> appendChild($scores ->createCDATASection ($_POST['header'])); //Add a CDATA element to it
$newGame -> appendChild($h); //Then append it to the game tag
```

With the comments, it should be quite straight-forward.

Comment: i tried this one and also posted the HTML codes without CDATA and it worked :)
i think the problem was just to remove the CDATA and let the code appear like that in the XML.. they are appearing correct on the main page

Comment: I still don't see what you are using the XML file for, but if you are going to retrieve it through some type of software this is probably the most correct way to go.

Comment: thats what im using it for http://leb-media.com/fouadlb/files/GermanySupporters/Scores/ :) ... the header tag posts a header like the Euro Qualifications and if its blank it doesnt post a header

Comment: never mind.. your genius ! the codes are being posted in the XML just perfect! i love you :)

Comment: hey mate are you there? i still have 1 lil problem :(.. yestarday we fixed the problem of posting the html codes in the XML file... u also made for me a script to edit the XML file, this one http://pastebin.com/tn9UtdAf ... so posting the HTML is working great with your solution, but when i edit them they are being edited and posted all again in the wrong format :S i think we need also to put this code to the EDIT page as we added it the ADD page.... i tried to mess around and make it work but i couldnt :P can i have lil help with this last thing xD! THANKS!

Comment: ok sorry i was editing the comment :P didnt know ur online hehe

Comment: I think it should look like this: http://pastebin.com/HpN6G9xV I'm quite surprised that it works, so it might be something wrong with it

Comment: haha you're awesome! i got ya some help with points! I really appreciate your help in the last couple days! THANKS! :)

Comment: :( hi again,
all working perfectly on wamp on my PC but when i uploaded it all working except the edit page http://leb-media.com/fouadlb/files/GermanySupporters/Scores/edit/edit.php when im editing a row im getting a `/` near every `'` open the link and try editing one by yourself... thats how the codes of it looks http://pastebin.com/fycn2ZWp , sorry for asking again :/

Comment: hey man :( i still didnt get this problem fixed :S

any idea why this happening ?:S

Comment: I don't know why that's happening, tried uploading your local xml file to the server for testing? It might contain something that the PHP doesn't like

Comment: yea.. i told yea my problem is just on the server but no on my pc i was creating the files on pc using wamp and all worked perfect with the scripts u gave me !!.. the problem came on the server in the Edit Script (script : http://pastebin.com/fycn2ZWp ) (edit page on the web: http://leb-media.com/fouadlb/files/GermanySupporters/Scores/edit/edit.php ) when i edit the Header or InfoData Tag of a row i get my HTML code messed up for that row only...  for example if i have this in the firt Header `<tr><td colspan='7' id='headertd'>` after editing anything in it or in the InfoData..

Comment: the codes do the change but also change it to `<tr><td colspan=\'7\' id=\'headertd\'>` that's really weird... try editing the InfoData of the second row.. check it by yourself :(

Comment: Strange... Which PHP version do u use on the public server?

Comment: Well, try to track down which function that adds the slashes, echo the variables out at some places until you find where the slash is added

Comment: i didn't get what you mean :( lol that's crazy we done all the work and we're stuck on this stupid little problem, i been told about something with unescaping or something like that but i don't know what's that.. and how to use it

Comment: Np, It just very hard to find something out when I don't have the same server setup.. I guess you could try to replace `$header = $game->getElementsByTagName("Header")->item(0)->nodeValue;` with `$header = stripslashes($game->getElementsByTagName("Header")->item(0)->nodeValue);`

Comment: well.. it worked on the page.. it was showing no slashes in the text area of the tags but it actually had slash in the xml code and messed up the output on the main page :/ but it not showing anymore slashes in the text area..

Comment: Im not sure if this is the way to go, but use javascripts unescape function to remove the slashes on the main page aswell

Comment: well it kinda worked... the xml still has the slashes but they aint showing on the main page just the  only problem is that i have used `'` near a number that indicate the mins when the goal was scored ( 30' ) and the slashes coming near this `'` are not being removed with the other ( 30\' )

Comment: If you add similar code to the other fields, it should be removed?

Comment: those ( 30' ) are in the InfoData tag and already has this code :(

Comment: If you still have the problem (I don't see it on your site), try to use javascripts unescape(str) function

Comment: i dont have it coz i changed the xml using FTP.. can u tell me how and where i could use the unescape function ? i feel im so annoying lol look how many comments :P

Comment: It looks like you are outputting the results through PHP? I thought you used Javascript for that. Just use unescape(orginalString) where retrieve the data if it's in JS or the PHP stripslashes(orginalString) if you are using PHP to output it.

Comment: i did that before mate, i told u it worked the codes showing no problem for the HTML codes only.. but if i have a `'` in my text inside the HTML tags, its also getting a slash near it.. so the stripslash on the output work on the html codes only and not removing the \ added by the edit page in the text between the html tags

Comment: I think I found the problem, it outputs correctly but the browser parses the ' so that it isn't displayed? If that's the case, you probably could do something like `$time = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($game->getElementsByTagName("Time")->item(0)->nodeValue));` where you are outputting it (both `htmlspecialchars` and `stripslashes`)

Comment: i keep the stripslashes on the Edit page and i put stripslashes and htmlspecialchars on the main page that display the tags ?

Comment: on the main page that display the XML i have for each tag `$Headers= $Game->getElementsByTagName( "Header" );
  $Header= $Headers->item(0)->nodeValue;`
i have added first the strip slash like that
`$Headers = $game->getElementsByTagName("Header")->item(0)->node‌​Value;
  $Header= stripslashes($Headers->item(0)->nodeValue);` then u said now to add htmlspecialchars also so i changed it to  `$Headers = $game->getElementsByTagName("Header")->item(0)->node‌​Value;
  $Header= htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($Headers->item(0)->nodeValue));` after changing the page is not showing anything anymore

Comment: i still think that the problem is in the edit page coz when im editing im getting these \ which causing the problem that we trying to solve it with these htmlspecialchar and stripslashes on the main page. check the code of the edit page before adding any specialchars to it. that's my Edit.php page http://pastebin.com/KSGjU6z5 and thats my main page http://pastebin.com/FKVkGJPZ and that's the XML file http://pastebin.com/ZE8FA8MY those are the pages that were working perfect on PC but not on server. edit page adding this  \ thing near the ' for the row that i edit only (for InfoData & Header)

Comment: Please move extended discussions to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com). Keep comments relevant to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should simply not use CDATA. There's a bunch of issues with it; By leaving it out I believe everything will work as expected.

What you have right now is effectively a double-encoding (using CDATA and added entities), so the result will be wrong in this case.

Comment: what do you mean with cname ? sorry im not so good in php, i got help to make this code...
can you tell me what should i do? or what code should i add to avoid html tranformation...
i have this code
<?php 
   $baseurl = '<base_url>';
?>
<font class="font_style"><?php echo htmlspecialchars ($baseurl);?></font> but i have no idea how to use it in my case

Comment: Sorry.. i meant cdata.. get rid of that:)

Comment: the CDATA is not the problem.. i tried writing HTML codes without CDATA and same problem

Comment: Ok in that case.. show us what the current output is (without CDATA!) and show us the output you expect. That will help

Comment: mate, i can't use HTML codes inside XML tag without the CDATA thing...
to show you... i posted the same thing without CDATA i got that... &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td colspan='7' id='headertd'&gt;&#13; 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#13;
&lt;img border='0' src='images/euro.png' /&gt;&#13;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#13;
UEFA Euro 2012 Qualifications&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;     i got the same thing but without CDATA tags...

Comment: Yes.. well with our without CDATA this is exactly equivalent. Even though it doesn't look as nice when entities are encoded, it is the better way to do it. CDATA is a bad idea.. trust me; Coincidentally I also had to work with xml feeds for soccer results for several bigger news sites :)

Comment: can u give me a way to replace the CDATA ? :/ ... adding HTML codes to a TAG in XML doesnt work and i rly need to add these codes..

Comment: What I mean is, the last output you gave me (in this comment) looks correct to me. It's exactly what I would expect. Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: im tring to write in the XML file this `<![CDATA[<tr><td colspan='7' id='headertd'>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img border='0' src='images/euro.png' />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
UEFA Euro 2012 Qualifications</td></tr>]]>` and im using PHP script as i mentioned to submit the info to the XML file all the info are working good but when im trying to add this HTML code using the script its being wrote on the XML the way i posted in the question... thats all the problem

Comment: well mate i added to my code `htmlentities($_POST['header'])` and posted the HTML without a CDATA first and even the info is written in non HTML im getting the result i want on the page! thanks for trying to help! :)

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I meant all along :P And even though the result is the same as the CDATA solution (now). This solution is actually slightly better. With the CDATA you can still end up with corrupt XML in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

The code behind the form is probably saving the form values using something like:

```
htmlentities($xml_string);
```

If you are using a framework to handle the form submission it is possible that there is a flag that could be passed (True/False) to tell the framework to NOT use htmlentities when saving the data.  However, make sure you are still validating the field in some way to prevent injection security holes. (Ex. - if storing in a DB use mysql_real_escape_string() or similar.)

You could try:

```
$scores = new DOMDocument();
$scores->substituteEntities = false;
$scores->load('../scores.xml');
```

Comment: but im using PHP with XML not DB... :/

Comment: You could try: $scrores->substituteEntities =false; before you do $scores -> load('../scores.xml');

Comment: If you try using $scores -> loadHTMLFile('../scores.xml'); after the line I put above instead of just a plain load(); (grasping at straws to try and help)

Comment: also didn't work page got tons of errors the xml cant be read :(

Comment: Pardon my OCD, but just for sanity check you are doing the instantiation, then setting the substitutes=false, then loading...right?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just let it look like that in the xml file, and when you retrieve it you would use the PHP function `htmlspecialchars_decode` to convert them back.

Example:

```
<?php
$s = "&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td colspan='7' id='headertd'&gt;&#xD;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#xD;
    &lt;img border='0' src='images/euro.png' /&gt;&#xD;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#xD;
    UEFA Euro 2012 Qualifications&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;"; 
//The orginal $s is retrieved from the XML file

$s = htmlspecialchars_decode($s);
echo $s; //The orginal code is printed
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can i know where should i put it in the code i posted, please! ? :)

Comment: Depends on where you output the contents of the XML file, you have some type of user interface, right?

Comment: thx for ur reply!... theres no user interface im just making the work easier for me by using this form to post the data into the XML file :) so it will post the information correctly on my page :) that's all i need...

Comment: it's so frustrating i can't find a solution :( you helped me get all done really good adding-editing-deleting but i can't get this problem done ! been 2 days im stuck on it :/

Comment: i edited ur post coz i thought i found the solution and wanted u to accept my edit so i accept your answer but than u gave me a way better answer :) so i re-edit ur post and made it as you posted it :D

Comment: Ok good, I don't think you should edit to change the answer completley anyways